# How to move column in rows direction in Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

For example, I want get right from left DataFrame like on picture (move column B on 2 steps down):

[image: Pandas Example]

PS. "Na" is not necessary, it can be any controlled value like null, zero or empty string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) method for this:

```
df["B"] = df["B"].shift(2)
```

The value used for the first two rows (NA or something else) can be controlled using the `fill_value` argument.